# running app in background

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors

```
package com.example.shake;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
  private SensorManager sensorManager;
  private boolean color = false;
  private View view;
  private long lastUpdate;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    view = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
  }

  @Override
  public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
      getAccelerometer(event);
    }

  }

  private void getAccelerometer(SensorEvent event) {
    float[] values = event.values;
    // Movement
    float x = values[0];
    float y = values[1];
    float z = values[2];
    double latitude=0;
    double longitude=0;
    String location_message;
    GPSTracker gps;

    float accelationSquareRoot = (x * x + y * y + z * z)
        / (SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH * SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH);
    long actualTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (accelationSquareRoot >= 2.4) //
    {
      if (actualTime - lastUpdate < 200) {
        return;
      }
      lastUpdate = actualTime;
      gps=new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);
      if(gps.canGetLocation()){    
        latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        longitude = gps.getLongitude();
        // \n is for new line
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
        try{
         List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
         location_message= addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        if (addresses.size() > 0) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is "     +addresses.get(0).getLocality()
            , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print(e);
        }
    }else{
        // can't get location
        // GPS or Network is not enabled
        // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Switch on gps"
                , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        gps.showSettingsAlert();
    }


      /*Toast.makeText(this, "Device was shuffed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
          .show();
      if (color) {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

      } else {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
      }*/
      color = !color;
    }
   }

  @Override
       public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

   }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // register this class as a listener for the orientation and
    // accelerometer sensors
    sensorManager.registerListener(this,
        sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    // unregister listener
    super.onPause();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
   }
}
```

This code gives the current location when you shake the mobile.I want to create an app that monitors the shake parameter in the background and automatically display the location.I know that it can be done by the Service class in android but being a beginner i don't know how to implement it.Is there any other way to do it? Could anyone help me out

Answer (score 1):

Look at this sample code : You need to implement listeners as shown.

```
public class Accelerometer extends Service implements AccelerometerListener{ private static 
Context CONTEXT;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
// TODO Put your code here
return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
System.out.println(”start listening”);
// if (AccelerometerManager.isSupported()) { AccelerometerManager.startListening(this);

// }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
System.out.println(”stop listening”);
// if (AccelerometerManager.isListening()) { AccelerometerManager.stopListening();
// }
}



/**
* onShake callback
*/
public void onShake(float force) {
Toast.makeText(this, “Phone shaked omha ya 3ammi el7ag: ” + force,             1000).show(); }

/**
* onAccelerationChanged callback
*/
public void onAccelerationChanged(float x, float y, float z) { System.out.println(”x =     “+x+” y = “+y+” z = “+z); }

}
```

Please follow  this [link](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.in/2010/04/monitoring-sensors-in-background.html) for your additional info